# How do you test app translations with pseudolocales on mobile Samsung devices?

Tags: android, mobile

Our client is trying to test the app we've been building for them on a couple of Samsung Galaxy devices (S9, S8 and S7). The problem is that they can't find the option to add `English (XA)` in the settings menu, even though they're following the steps from [Google's guide page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/pseudolocales). They also can't provide us for the moment with translations for any of the languages they want to support, so the pseudolocale is the only way we can test for hardcoded strings. How do you guys test for translation errors on Samsung devices?